# Captura de errores

Tags: java

Tengo un problema, que como no tengo acceso a la configuración del servidor, me está resultando dificil ver que ocurre. Yo en mis servidores, cuando lanzo un error desde mi código Java, tengo en el web.xml la siguiente instrucción:

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/errorPage.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Pues bien, en mis servidores, todo ok, me muestra la página de error que dependiendo del mensaje que le ponga en el error que lanzo, me pone una cosa u otra. Ahora bien, en otros servidores, tuvimos que poner que capturara el error 500, para que no saliera nada del tomcat, ok, pero desde entonces, esos errores Throwable, no se muestran, y simplemente pone página no encontrada (bueno, muestra la página que tienen ellos configurada como error). Me aseguran que sólo han añadido en el tomcat para que capture el error 500 (me lo creeré), pero yo en mis servidores también lo tengo, y me salen bien mis errores. ¿A alguien mas le pasa esto? ¿Puede ser por tema de diferentes versiones del Tomcat?

No se si me he explicado bien, si eso preguntad!! ;)

Un saludo y gracias!

Comment: Si lo que quieres ver es la traza del error, ¿no es más sencillo mirar los ficheros de log? No debes depender del contenedor para ver los mensajes de error

Comment: Hola, gracias por contestar. El asunto es que cuando lanzo algún UserException por ejemplo, con un mensaje, la página de error los captura, y muestra el error claro para el usuario, diciendo como ha de actuar para solucionarlo. Cuando pusieron en el servidor que capturara el error 500 y mostrara la página que ellos tienen por defecto para los errores, ya no salen las explicaciones del error, con lo cual, el usuario se queda sin saber que ha pasado.
Yo entro en el log y veo que ocurre, pero necesito que el usuario vea el problema, y lo solucione por si mismo. 
Gracias de nuevo!